# Where can I find the function definition and documentation that explain this call in Drupal APIs?

Tags: php, api, drupal-7, bitnami

In a Drupal project, the following calls are being made. in different APIs

```
<?php
     function GetAllCities($decrypted_json)
     {
         echo file_get_contents(public_url."city-view");
     }
?>
```

Moreover I see the following in different scripts:

```
echo file_get_contents(public_url."stylist-services?stylistnid=".$decrypted_json->stylistnid);
echo file_get_contents(public_url."sub-category-view");
```

**Now I am unable to get to the definition of the following calls in the above code:**

1. city-view
2. stylist-services
3. stylistnid
4. sub-category-view

When I echo the public_url, I get the following response

```
http://x.x.x.x/drupal/
```

I am just looking for a way to understand what these calls are and what these do. There is no documentation, no comments, no hint.
Let me know if I can provide any more information.

Comment: file_get_contents is a standard PHP function, not specific to Drupal. It reads the contents of the given file into a string. http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php . It can also be used to retrieve the content from a URI rather than a local file, which seems to be what it's doing in your example. Is it this function you don't understand, or you want definitions of what the URI endpoints it's calling are supposed to return? If they aren't standard Drupal features, they might be part of the specific project, and documentation may/may not be available as per that project.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I will update the question with more details. I am interested in the city-view, stylist-services and the sub-category-view part definitions.

Comment: I may be wrong but they don't sound like standard services of a CMS to me, they sound like something specific to that project. Certainly googling those services names returns nothing useful. So you should probably check the project's docs first. If it doesn't have any, ask the developers.

Comment: Unfortunately, I came here as a last resort.  You are right about googling, there was no such thing in the results. Moreover the complete lack of documentation has left me in the dark. And one more thing, I used sublime text to search the entire project for those lines of code e.g. "sub-category-view" and there was nothing found.

Comment: I don't know how drupal works in detail, but is it possible some of this stuff is configured and held in the database rather than project files? That might explain its absence from the code files. Either that or that code doesn't work properly. Or possibly there's no specific method called that, but perhaps it's a naming convention whereby there might be "sub-category" somewhere specified, and then "view" appended to it tells the code something about what to do. I don't know for sure, but those are design patterns I've seen before in other systems.

Comment: Is there really no-one left who wrote or maintained this who you can talk to?

Comment: ADyson, you might be very close. I visited 'http://123.123.123.123/drupal/city-view . This link is indirectly called by an API like 'echo file_get_contents(public_url."city-view");'  and it showed me the list of cities in JSON format. What can you deduce from this?

Comment: Not at lot really. It shows you a list. We don't know if that's the only function - maybe you get different data if you pass some parameters to it (e.g. to restrict the list). Who knows, without seeing the method or any docs. Maybe you should read the Drupal docs to see how views are defined in that framework. There will be a structured way to do it, so then you might be able to logically work out which bit of code is providing that function, and then read it to understand what it can and cannot do. If you're _really_ lucky the code may be commented in a useful way explaining the functionality

Comment: ADyson, you did it! I was looking at Drupal Views all the time. I even made a test view and accessed it using 123.123.123.123/drupal/my-test-view  which was showing me exactly what I made i.e. filtered and customized data which also accepted certrain filtered data parameters.

This is exactly what I was looking for  [Drupal Views module](https://www.drupal.org/docs/7/modules/views)

ADyson, Answer this question and I will accept as a valid answer. Thanks.

Comment: done - thanks. Let me know if you want any more detail in the answer or that's enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We don't know exactly what those functions do just from the names - maybe you get different data if you pass some parameters to it (e.g. to restrict the list). Who knows, without seeing the method or any docs.

You should read the Drupal docs to see how views are defined in that framework. There will be a structured way to do it, so then you might be able to logically work out which bit of code is providing that function, and then read it to understand what it can and cannot do. If you're really lucky the code may be commented in a useful way explaining the functionality!